How to resume an upload to GCS after an interruption with Golang?
In my Go program, I am uploading a multi-gigabyte file to Google Cloud Storage (GCS). I am using the client library here: https://pkg.go.dev/cloud.google.com/go/storage
My code is similar to the example in the documentation. r is a file reader:
client, err := storage.NewClient(ctx)
if err != nil {
    return err
}
defer client.Close()
w := client.Bucket(l.Bucket).Object(fileName).NewWriter(ctx)
w.ContentType = ""
w.ACL = []storage.ACLRule{{Entity: storage.AllUsers, Role: storage.RoleReader}}

if _, err := io.Copy(w, r); err != nil {
    return err  // ########## Error is returned on this line! ##########
}
if err := w.Close(); err != nil {
    return err
}

Small files succeed. However, for large files that take over an hour to upload, my laptop will go to sleep before the upload completes. When my laptop wakes, the connection is interrupted and the following error is returned (I scrubbed the IP addresses for privacy):
read tcp x.x.x.x:ppp->X.X.X.X:PPP: read: connection reset by peer

Instead, I want to resume the upload. From the GCS documentation, I see that resumable uploads are supported (https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/resumable-uploads), but I am unsure how to use this functionality from the Go client.
One last important detail: I do not want to retry the upload from the beginning. I want to continue and retain the progress from before the interrupt.

Interesting question. I don't know the answer. An issue is that you don't want to return on the "connection reset" and so you don't want the error to arise from the writer for it. When you return/exit you lose context and I suspect (!) your client loses the session URL that GCS provides that enables it to continue. Can you try inserting an ObjectHandle.Retryer? see storage-configure-retries

Thank you! I gave it a shot. The WithPolicy(RetryAlways) option seemed the most relevant, but to no avail. I think the problem is staring right at me in the documentation, "RetryAlways causes all operations to be retried when the service returns a transient error". For some reason, the error is not considered transient.

See retry strategies

I think you're on to something, especially in this part, "The only exception to this behavior is when performing resumable uploads using Writer, where the data is large enough that it requires multiple requests. In this scenario, each chunk times out and stops retrying after 32 seconds by default. You can adjust the default timeout by changing Writer.ChunkRetryDeadline." I am going to give it a try right now!

Unfortunately, w.ChunkRetryDeadline = 7 * 24 * 60 * 60 * time.Second // 1 week has the same problem. Even using both a large ChunckRetryDeadline and WithPolicy(RetryAlways), the error is still the same.

The “resumable” part of the upload is only valid as long as your program is running. The session URI needed for resuming is used internally and stored in memory, so you can basically resume the upload with the last chunk in case of a short network outage.
When the used HTTP client gives up (after your notebook goes to sleep) you receive an error and the session is lost.
I see four options here:

Manipulate the HTTP client to not give up (not really recommended)
Use the gcloud binary (python)
Roll your own, using resumable uploads, storing the session somewhere
Roll your own, using signed URLs

I would suggest using signed URLs, but every solution has it's pros and cons.

Thank you! One thing to add is the Go program's memory is preserved while the laptop is asleep. It is the TCP connection which is being dropped. I think it might be the case that the client is not designed to resume for this kind of disruption.

You can upload the file in multiple chunks and use the Composer to concatenate the chunks. If a single chunk fails to upload, you can restart the one chunk without losing the whole upload. Here is some example code:
First, create a defer call for cleaning up temporary objects:
tmpObjectNames := map[string]struct{}{}
defer func() {                                                                                                                                                             
        for o := range tmpObjectNames {
                if err := bucket.Object(o).Delete(context.Background()); err != nil {
                        log.Printf("Failed to delete temporary object on GCS, %q: %v", o, err)          
                }
        }                        
}()       

Next, define some relevant constants. I am using the github.com/cenkalti/backoff package for performing retry logic:
const chunkSize = 128 * 1024 * 1024 // 128MiB
const composeLimit = 32 // defined in https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/compose
var backOffPolicy = backoff.WithMaxRetries(backoff.NewExponentialBackOff(), 5)

Here is the core upload logic (where f is the file being uploaded, fi.Size() is the size of the file and destObject is the destination on GCS):
var bytesWritten int64
var lastCRC32C uint32
var composeObjects []*storage.ObjectHandle
for bytesWritten < fi.Size() {
        chunkObject := bucket.Object(fmt.Sprintf("%s.part.%d", destObject.ObjectName(), bytesWritten))
        composeObjects = append(composeObjects, chunkObject)

        checkpoint, err := f.Seek(0, io.SeekCurrent)
        if err != nil {
                return err
        }
        if err := backoff.Retry(
               func() error {
                        // Seek to the beginning of the chunk in case upload failed
                        // in a previous iteration.
                        if _, err := f.Seek(checkpoint, io.SeekStart); err != nil {
                                return err
                        }

                        // Write one chunk.
                        w := chunkObject.NewWriter(context.Background())
                        w.ContentType = ""
                        n, err := io.CopyN(w, f, chunkSize)
                        if err != nil && !errors.Is(err, io.EOF) {
                                w.Close()
                                return err
                        }
                        if err := w.Close(); err != nil {
                                return err
                        }

                        // Chunk written successful. Update the counter.
                        bytesWritten += n
                        return nil
                },
                backOffPolicy); err != nil {
                return err
        }
        tmpObjectNames[chunkObject.ObjectName()] = struct{}{}

        // Concatenate all the files into the destination file.  GCS limits how
        // many objects can be composed at once, so this is performed
        // periodically.
        if len(composeObjects) == composeLimit || bytesWritten == fi.Size() {
                attrs, err := backoff.RetryWithData(func() (*storage.ObjectAttrs, error) {
                        return destObject.ComposerFrom(composeObjects...).Run(context.Background())
                }, backOffPolicy)
                if err != nil {
                        return fmt.Errorf("failed to compose objects into %q: %v", destObject.ObjectName(), err)
                }
                lastCRC32C = attrs.CRC32C
                composeObjects = []*storage.ObjectHandle{destObject}
        }
}

Finally, check lastCRC32C against the CRC of your local file. Golang's standard library contains a hash/crc32 package for this purpose.
This implementation has drawbacks: 1. The storage costs may be higher because more operations are being performed. 2. It deletes objects, which may not be suitable for all storage classes.
